# Flaskのアプリをherokuにpushできない

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Herokuを使って、Flaskのアプリケーションをpushしたいと思ってます。

Djangoの時はうまくいきましたが、

以下のようにrequirements.txtを記載し、

```
distribute
psycopg2==2.5.1
Flask
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-SocketIO==0.4.3
Jinja2==2.7.2
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
gevent==1.0
gevent-socketio==0.3.6
gevent-websocket==0.9.2
gunicorn==19.2.1
httplib2==0.9
```

distributeのバージョンを記載してハマってるのも見たので
バージョンを抜いたりしました。

Procfileもファイルの名前も大文字と小文字気をつけて、

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file -
```

を記載してます。

しかし、

```
git push heroku master
```

のコマンドで失敗します。

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 49, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Writing objects: 100% (49/49), 13.59 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 49 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)


 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:sugichat.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sugichat.git'
```

Djangoの時はrequirements.txtのファイルを忘れた時に一度ハマりましたが
今回は忘れてないのにどうしてもHerokuのリポジトリにpush出来ません。
ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Herokuはアプリのためにキーファイルが必要ですがそのキーファイルが見つからないです。 
そのファイルはおそらく：
php: index.php
python: requirements.txt
ruby: Gemfile
node: package.json

そうではなければも一回Ｇｉｔをやり直してみてくだいさい。

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -am "Reinitialize"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。
やはり「.git」を消さないとダメなのですね。
海外の方(？)なのに日本語でありがとうございました。
一度消せばpush出来ました。

でもなぜ消さないといけないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

> でもなぜ消さないといけないのでしょうか？

私の環境では、.git ファイルを消すようなことをしなくても、スムーズに Heroku への push ができています。一般的な話としては、下記のような問題が考えられるのではないでしょうか。

- requirements.txt のスペルミス
- requirements.txt を repository に追加し忘れていた

  - ディレクトリ内にファイルが存在していても、それを git のリポジトリに commit していないと意味が無いです
- カスタムの buildpack を指定していて、その buildpack が別の Cedar ファイルを要求していた
- package.json など、python よりも上位に位置づけられる buildpack 用のファイルが存在する（この場合、[Buildpack Multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi)やカスタムの buildpack が必要になる）

  - 参考: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks